# Is cheating in gambling also considered as gambling?

Tags: halal-haram, money, gambling

I found an exploit to hack an online casino mobile app which of course I never played before because it is `haram`. If not then why do I bother asking here ? But if I use the exploit, it will plots me a table of all incoming pseudo-random values so I know when is the right time to bet. If I'm not mistaken I think it's not anymore qualified to be called a gambling. It's more suitable to call it cheating and the one I cheat is the gambling operator company who was cheating peoples' money. My question is it permissible for me to take the prize money ?

Comment: Cheating is not allowed regardless of who you do it against. Also, I don't think the gambling operator is cheating per se. He is rather committing the sin of gambling.

Comment: Every gambler gambles because they think they can beat the odds. So I think knowing a way to beat the odds, even if cheating, still counts as gambling.